# Proving that $∂U = \overline U \cap \overline{X\setminus U}$

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that $$∂U = \overline U \cap \overline{X\setminus U}.$$

Not too sure where to start with this question so any help would be appreciated.

I am also struggling to prove $U^{\circ} \subset U$ for any $U$. I have the following definitions: $$∂U = \overline U \setminus U^{\circ},\ U^{\circ} = X\setminus \overline{(X\setminus U)}.$$

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just to confirm $\ U^{\circ} = X\setminus \overline{(X\setminus U)}$ is the given definition of interior, right?

Comment: @ir7 yes sorry that is the definition of interior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given definition of interior, we have:

$$∂U = \overline U \setminus U^{\circ} =\overline U \setminus( X\setminus \overline{(X\setminus U)}) = \overline U \cap \overline{(X\setminus U)}.$$

Also:

$$ U^{\circ} =X\setminus \overline{(X\setminus U)} \subset X\setminus (X\setminus U) = U, $$
as $X\setminus U \subset \overline{(X\setminus U)}$.

Comment: thank you so much! :)

Comment: You’re welcome.